# Cancel Auto-Renewable Subscription in In-app purchase

Tags: ios

I use Auto-Renewable Subscription in my application, When I test it. I want to cancel Auto-Renewable Subscription in `Sandbox environment` but I can't find it like this [link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202039)

More question: 
If sandbox environment don't allow cancel Auto-Renewable Subscription. So, Beta testing with `testflight` Can I do it?

Answer (score 7):

**Updates for IOS14**

IOS 14 have option to cancel subscription in sandbox environment.

Go to iPhone's *Settings>App Store*

Scroll down you can find *SANDBOX ACCOUNT* and can see your **Test Apple id** there, click on it, choose Manage(If you already subscribed you can see your selected product here).

You can see "**Cancel Subscription**". click on it and confirm.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know u can cancel auto renewable subscription only as a user, not as a dev or tester. The link you provided is the only way to cancel auto renewable subscription.

Comment: How to get notified if the user  cancel an auto renewable subscription?I want to cancel this on my server as well.

Comment: You will be notified once you start the application. When you hit appleserver with the last reciept you have saved, it will return you the code for cancellation of subscription. You can look it up and then confirm you server that the subscription has been cancelled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply saheb.So are you saying that the cancellation will generate a new reciept which contain information about cancled subscription?

Comment: After cancellation, on startup, you call apple server, with the old reciept.
Then apple will sent an error code, is_cancelled flag as 1 for the last purchase of subscription. You then can inform your server about the cancellation of the subscription. and also fetch the current reciept after the call.

Comment: Have you done this ?What if we have multiple subscriptions?How do we know which plan is cancelled?We will have to save and send all receipts right?

Comment: Actually I have written a class for subscription purpose. I am still working on it. The class wasnt meant for multiple subscription but you can do that.
Normally once you sent the receipt request to apple, apple will sent you the details of all subscription from your account to the application. 
Past and current all of them. You need to sort out by the subscription id and the date/time.